# Hangul calligraphy (TTF)

Tags: fonts, css3

I want a nice hangul font. Can somebody indicate one ? Something elegant and beautiful like this England calligraphy:

[image: Calligraphy]

I would like to apply it using css 3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">

        <style>
            @font-face {
                font-family: "hangul";
                src: url("hangul.ttf");
            }

            body {
                font-family: hangul;
            }
        </style>

        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        컴 투 미
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Korean.html - wrong forum though. :)

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not a "programmer" question.

Comment: Did FontSquirrel help you out or did you find what you needed?

Answer (score 1):

Please remember when using TTF's that not all browsers support it. Internet Explorer, while it does support the CSS3 @Font-face attribute, but it will only use .eot fonts.

From experience, if I have a TTF font and I want to convert this to EOT and SVG font files, the quality will be compromised. It will appear blocky and disgusting.

So, I would recommend using a website called http://www.fontsquirrel.com/. This will provide you with all the fonts you need and the CSS code you need to make the font accessible to all browsers. It also hosts a converter but be warned the quality of the font it produces is shocking.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of free fonts on the web. Rather then listing the web sites for you, I would suggest searching "free fonts". You can usually select a category of 'script' or 'calligraphy'.

Comment: +1 for stating the obvious, why there were 2 downvotes when the answer was clearly helpfull?